# Cache actuator endpoint not showing

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator, spring-boot-admin

I am implementing actuators and Spring Boot Admin to my application. When I send request to /actuators i get all actuator points except caches.

I have tried to turn ON/OFF cache health monitoring in application.yaml but didn't work.

```
cache: 
     hazelcast:
       instance_name: hazelcast-cache
       health:
         monitoring:
           level: OFF
```

application.yaml:

```
    web:
      exposure:
        include: "*"
```

build.gradle:

````
compile group: 'de.codecentric', name: 'spring-boot-admin-starter-client', version: '2.0.6'```
````

Comment: The application.yaml you included doesn't seem to be correct, I think you're missing the "management.endpoints" part of it. the full path to that property is:
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was spring boot version, my project was on 2.0.6. After migration to latest version everything is there.